# cholrank1 update with LDL decomposition

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have cholrank1 update procedure ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Updating_the_decomposition)) for the symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix.

```
function [L] = cholupdate(L,x)
    p = length(x);
    for k=1:p
        r = sqrt(L(k,k)^2 + x(k)^2);
        c = r / L(k, k);
        s = x(k) / L(k, k);
        L(k, k) = r;
        L(k+1:p,k) = (L(k+1:p,k) + s*x(k+1:p)) / c;
        x(k+1:p) = c*x(k+1:p) - s*L(k+1:p,k);
    end
end
```

It works with LL decomposition. I try to fix procedure to work with LDL decomposition (ie without calling sqrt) like this:

```
function [L] = cholupdate_ldl(L,x)
    p = length(x);
    for k=1:p
        r = L(k,k) + x(k)^2;
        c = r / L(k, k);
        s = x(k) / L(k, k);
        L(k, k) = r;
        L(k+1:p,k) = (L(k+1:p,k) + s*x(k+1:p)) / c;
        x(k+1:p) = sqrt(c)*(x(k+1:p) - x(k)*L(k+1:p,k));
    end
end
```

It works fine but I was forced to use sqrt. How can I update LDL decomposition without using sqrt at all?

Comment: The definition of LDL decomposition is not "without calling sqrt". Its a decomposition that computes L*D*L thus optputing 2 matrices.

Comment: Yes. But with LDL decomposition I did not calculate sqrt of the diagonal element. Anyway, the question is - how can I update LDL decomposition without using sqrt at all?

Comment: I dont know much about it, but, why do you think you can?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways. See **Gill, Golub, Murray and Saunders (1974)**: [Methods for Modifying Matrix Factorizations](http://stanford.edu/group/SOL/papers/ggms74.pdf) in *Mathematics of Computation*. To summarize your question formally, I quote from the paper:

[image]

[image]

Finally we get to the algorithm:

[image]

And here is my implementation in MATLAB:

```
function [L1,D1] = ldlt_update(L0,D0,z)

n = size(L0,1) ;
D1 = zeros(n,n) ;
L1 = zeros(n,n) ;

a = 1 ;
w = z ;
for jj = 1:n
    p = w(jj) ;
    D1(jj,jj) = D0(jj,jj) + a*p^2 ;
    b = p*a/D1(jj,jj) ;
    a = D0(jj,jj)*a/D1(jj,jj) ;
    for r = jj+1:n
        w(r) = w(r) - p*L0(r,jj) ;
        L1(r,jj) = L0(r,jj) + b*w(r) ;
    end
end
end
```

There is an alternative algorithm in the paper cited above and in **Gill, Murray, and Wright (1982)**: [Practical Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122839528). Brian Borchers has a complete set of MATLAB code for working with real symmetric positive definite LDLT factorizations as defined in **Golub and Van Loan (2013)**: *Matrix Computations* and on [his web site](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~borchers/ldlt.html).

Comment: it's a pleasure! I am glad it was helpful to you.